# Can you please check my limit proof

Tags: real-analysis

I proved the following:

If $x_n \to x$ then $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$

How I proved it: First I proved it for $x=0$. Then:  Let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $x_n \to x$ then $(x_n - x) \to 0$. Since we have shown for $x=0$ we may assume that $x \neq 0$. Then
$$ x_n - x = (\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}) $$
implies 
$$ {x_n - x \over \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x}$$
Since $\lim \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x} = 2 \sqrt{x}$ and $x \neq 0$ it follows that 
$$\lim \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} = \lim {x_n - x \over \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}} = 0$$
and therefore $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you used your conclusion to prove your conclusion, when you said: "Since $\lim\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt x=2\sqrt x$...."

It's also worth noting that you must be **very** careful with your proof in the case that $x=0$. For example, consider the sequence $x_n=-\frac1n.$

It would be more accurate (in the context of real analysis) to say the following:

> For any $x\ge 0$ and any sequence of non-negative numbers $x_n,$ if $x_n\to x,$ then $\sqrt{x_n}\to\sqrt x.$

I leave the case that $x=0$ to you. For the $x>0$ case, we can use the observation that $$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}.$$ Show that for any $\epsilon>0,$ we can find $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt x\ge\frac54\sqrt x$ (**hint**: $t\mapsto\sqrt t$ is an increasing function on the non-negative reals) and $|x_n-x|<\frac54\epsilon\sqrt x.$

Hence, for any $\epsilon>0,$ we can find $N$ such that for all $n\ge N,$ we have $$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\le\cfrac{|x_n-x|}{\frac54\sqrt{x}}<\cfrac{\frac54\epsilon\sqrt{x}}{\frac54\sqrt{x}}=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you. I thought the proof was too complicated and I found an easier proof: $$ {|x_n - x| \over \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}} \le {|x_n - x| \over \sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: The case with $x=0$ is easy: Assume $x_n \to 0$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $|x_n - 0| = x_n < \varepsilon^2$. Then for $n > N$, $|\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{0}| = \sqrt{x_n} < \varepsilon$

Comment: Oooh! I like that better! Yes, since $\sqrt{x_n}\ge 0$ for all $x_n,$ then $\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt x\ge \sqrt x>0,$ and so the inequality you mention holds, so instead, we'll only need to find $N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon\sqrt x$ for $n>N.$ Your proof for the $x=0$ case looks good, if you can justify that $x_n<\epsilon^2\implies\sqrt{x_n}<\epsilon.$

Comment: Yes, I can, the square root function is increasing because it is zero at zero and the derivative is $>0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Yep! That does the trick.